# How do I change the color of an anti aliased text with gimp

Tags: gimp

I am stuck changing the color of a text on a gif. Because the text
is anti aliased I cannot use the bucket tool. How would I do that.

It seems to me that there should be something into which I can enter the
source color and the destination color and that "something" would then
interpolate the colors for me.

If this is not possible with gimp, I'd take any suggestion on how to do it with
another tool.

Comment: Look for Hue/Saturation or similar adjustments in the menus.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an old tutorial http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Changing_Background_Color_1/. Color to Alpha can be found in the Color menu.

Comment: The tutorial's a bit out of date now, the "Color to alpha" menu item is in the "Color" menu now. Other than that, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

For a GIF, first you want to be sure you're not using a palette.  Choose in the right-click menu Image -> Mode -> RGB.  Now you can do all kinds of things with color.  When done with the modifications, you may choose Image -> Mode -> Indexed to save the result as a GIF.

In the Colors menu (right click), choose Hue-Saturation. In the popup controls window, slide the Hue knob around.  Saturation might be useful too.

If that doesn't work quite right by itself, next thing I'd do is use a mask.  Selecting text by color, feather it by a couple pixels, and then try the Hue-Saturation.  Feathering it just right may take some re-tries.

There could be refinements to what I describe, depending on details - a sample of your image would help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are switching from light-background and dark-text to dark-background and light-text, one thing that helped me is Colors>Invert. That way, if you don't quite have the anti-aliased pixels selected perfectly, at least they are generally in the right ballpark - dark not light (or vice-versa if you are going the other way). You can use select-by-color on the text and perhaps feather the selection then change the main-text color as desired (thanks to DarenW for this suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

I would go Color to Alpha too if you want to specify the color with rgb to match something else in the image.

Answer (score -1):

Using a gradient map worked for me, with the gradient set to the desired color (sorry can't be more specific, but I have no idea what I'm doing with GIMP, which I think speaks well to the solution).

I got the answer here: http://www.gimptalk.com/index.php?/topic/46975-antialias-filling-with-a-different-color/

Comment: You should quote and cite all relevant information from your link.  You should provide more specifics, which you don't seem to have, so you should figure what the specifics are and edit your answer to include them.